# enforce triple quotes around strings in python

Tags: python, mysql, string, quote

I have a mysql table, which stores some sql queries.

The schema is like:

```
CREATE TABLE `queries` (`qry_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`qry_text` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`result_table` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`last_run` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`period` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`error` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`qry_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

For example, one qry text is `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 = '%s' and COL2 = '%s'`

In python, I pulled a str called qry from a sql table.

```
qry = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 = '%s' and COL2 = '%s' "
```

What I want is:

```
qry = """SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 = '%s' and COL2 = '%s' """ % (var1, var2)
```

How to artificially add triple quotes around qry and append % (var1, var2) to it. I need to pass qry (in the format I specified) to an API to run. Thanks!

Comment: You do know `""` is exactly the same as `""""""`

Comment: Tripple quotes are just a syntax to form strings. They are not part of the final produced string.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What exactly is in the sql table? Does it contain a query: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 = '%s' and COL2 = '%s'`? A python code fragment: `qry = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 = '%s' and COL2 = '%s' "`?

Comment: Also, sanatise your input. lest we forget little bobby droptables. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: You store `'qry = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 = '%s' and COL2 = '%s' "'` in you database. o_O (@JakobBowyer it's Bobby Tables …)

Comment: @Kay I store all kind of things in my database

Comment: @JakobBowyer that's alright as long as you don't intent to eval that strings. That question reads like OP is about to.

Comment: @Eric This is the table schema:                                 CREATE TABLE `queries` (
  `qry_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `qry_text` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `result_table` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_run` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `period` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `error` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`qry_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;                                               I pulled qry_text from this table and name it as qry

Comment: @Kay its not my question dude.

Comment: @tonystarkix: Add that to the question so that someone stands a chance of being able to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your problem:

```python
def get_dangerous_query():
    # do some database access
    # For a demo, just return what we know the table contains
    return "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 = '%s' and COL2 = '%s'"

qry = get_dangerous_query() % (var1, var2)
```

`"""` vs `"` only has an effect on string literals. Quotes are completely meaningless if a string comes from an external source.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Eric. problem solved. No need to use """

Comment: @tonystarkix: Remember to click the tick if this solved the problem